# What's a good WordPress Plugin Architecture?

Tags: wordpress, architecture, plugins

I'm building a wordpress plug-in but I'm thinking first of looking into an Open Source one which follows the best practices and has a good architecture.

What plug-in do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atahualpa is my personal favorite.